# Fitting images perfectly in a masonry layout

Tags: jquery-masonry

So I am designing an online portfolio and I am working on the masonry layout. Every thing is except I have a little bit of a gap at the bottom of the image;

https://jsfiddle.net/dzd3q58q/14/embedded/result/

```
.masonry .item,
.masonry .grid-sizer
```

Can anyone help in fixing this issue ?

Comment: Are you referring to the white space below the item  or the extra color background of the item showing?

Comment: I am talking about the extra color background

Answer (score 0):

First, your setting the height of these div's using h2, h3 as well as your .item  so of course they show the red since the height is larger than the image. Usually you would set the width, not height.
You also need to load masonry using imagesloaded so your layout won't be flakey since masonry is setting up the items before all the images are loaded.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/nqegqtcv/) with your CSS fixed by removing the heights and setting your grid-sizer separate from your item.

You can play with it.
Also, FYI, put your js in the External Resources of the jsFiddle, not in the js pane. Helps when you might be adding code that needs debugging.

CSS

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

img{
display:block;
height:auto;
max-width:100%;    
}


body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.masonry {
background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1800px;
margin:120px auto;    
}

.grid-sizer {
 width: width:100%;
 }
.masonry .item {
width: 100%;
float: left;
background: #D26;
border: 2px solid #333;
border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
border-radius:;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
.masonry .item,
.masonry .grid-sizer { width:  calc( ( 100% - 20px ) / 2 ); }
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
.masonry .item,
.masonry .grid-sizer { width:  calc( ( 100% - 40px ) / 3 ); }
.masonry .item.w2 { width:  calc( ( 100% - 20px ) / 2 ); }
.masonry .item.w3 { width:  calc( ( 100% - 40px ) * ( 2 / 3 ) + 20px); }
.masonry .item.w4 { width:  100%; }
  }
```

JS

```
var $container = $('#container');
 / initialize Masonry after all images have loaded  
 $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
 $container.masonry();
 });
```